# How to print the string or value held as True

Tags: python, if-statement

Say, I have a function in Python where

```
if (age<20):
    young=True
if (age>80):
    old=True
```

My question is, if I want to call or print the values which are held as True. 
I want to write this line: The person wasn't selected for the job because he was old/young etc. One person could also violate many criteria. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be sure: you want to print something if `old` or `height` is `True`.

```
   # This is needed if you want to check if old = false or true
   old = False
   height = False
```

Your begin is correct.

```
   if age>20: 
      old=True
   if height>90:
      tall=True
```

After this, you want to check if `old` or `height` is `True`, so

```
   if old:
       print("<Here your output>")
   if height:
       print("<Here your output>")
```

You can also combine height and old with `and, or, not`.

However, if you want to print "you're too old", you can also use

```
   if age>20: 
      print("<text>")
   if height>90:
      print("<text>")
```

Comment: Thanks! What if a person is both? Because for the sake of simplicity, I have just included age and height, but I have the weight criteria as well and all of this is in a range. Therefore, age less than 15 is too young and so on.

Comment: @user585380 By using `and` or `or` you can check if both or more are set `True`. Do you mean `for x in range(a,b):` for height, age and weight? Because if so, you will need to loop thru all three options. However, this will take a while, so it is not the fastest way. If I misunderstood your comment, please leave a comment so I can help you better.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much Jereme Mulder!

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary or a custom class. For an isolated call, a dictionary works fine. Here's an example where we initialize values for pre-specified keys as `False`:

```
# some arbitrary inputs
age, height = 25, 80

# create dictionary with "old" & "tall" keys with values to set to False
flags = dict.fromkeys(('old', 'tall'), False)

# set dictionary values to True conditionally
if age > 20:
    flags['old'] = True
if height > 90:
    flags['tall'] = True

# use list comprehension to iterate dictionary key-value pairs and 
# return list of keys where value is True
true_keys = [k for k, v in flags.items() if v]

print(true_keys)

['old']
```

Comment: Thank you! But I haven't been taught flags, or dict function. Is there a way I could do this with the if function. Please check out my edited question.

Comment: @user585380, No there isn't a *good* way with *just* the `if` function. I strongly suggest you learn about dictionaries. They are fairly elementary objects with a wide range of uses.

Comment: Okay. Could you explain the code to me step by step? Or could you just add in the answer itself, the meaning of each line of code. I'm sorry if this is asking for too much but I'm absolutely new to programming.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to jpp great answer, you can replace `if` statements like this:

```
age, height = 25, 80

flags = dict.fromkeys(('old', 'tall'), False)

flags['old'] = age > 20
flags['tall'] = height > 90

true_keys = [k for k, v in flags.items() if v]

print(true_keys)
```

Comment: Thank you! But I haven't been taught flags, or dict function. Is there a way I could do this with the if function. Please check out my edited question.

Comment: @user585380, No there isn't a *good* way with *just* the `if` function. I strongly suggest you learn about dictionaries. They are fairly elementary objects with a wide range of uses.

Comment: What does k for k, v in flags.items() if v mean?